# php sessions doesn't work with form when submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm having an exam soon. I'm stuck with sessions. At most cases it does not work to me. No matter what I have tried. It worked for me once, but after refreshing a page I never saw it worked. My samples:

qwer.php:

```
<?php
session_name('Private'); 
session_id('TEST');
if(isset($_POST["Submit"])){
session_start();
$_SESSION['counter']=5;
$_SESSION["lolvalue"]=isset($_POST["imie"]);
}
?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="myform" method="post" action="qwew.php" onsubmit="return validateform();">
    <input type="text" name="imie"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit">
    </form>
    <a href='qwew.php'>Link to protected file</a>
    </body>
    </html>

<script type="text/javascript">function validateform(){
checkit=/^[A-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{7,16}$/;
if(!(myform.imie.value.match(checkit))){alert("blabla...bla");
return false;}
}
</script>
```

qwew.php

```
<?php
session_name('Private');
session_id('TEST');
session_start();

echo "here it is: ".$_SESSION["lolvalue"]." and ".$_SESSION["counter"];

session_destroy();

?>
```

The thing is that form and redirecting to another page should be done by clicking on submit. Please help me to figure out where I am wrong.
Also I forgot to mension I'm using XAMPP, session.use_cookies and session.use_trans_sid are enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### qwer.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST["Submit"])) {
        $_SESSION['counter']=5;
        $_SESSION["lolvalue"]=isset($_POST["imie"]);
        header('Location:qwew.php');
        die(); 
    }
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" method="post" action="qwer.php" onsubmit="return validateform();">
    <input type="text" name="imie"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
<a href='qwew.php'>Link to protected file</a>
</body>
</html>
```

### qwew.php

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["lolvalue"]) && isset($_SESSION["counter"]))
 echo "here it is: ".$_SESSION["lolvalue"]." and ".$_SESSION["counter"];
else {
   header('Location:qwer.php');
   die(); 
 }
```

Comment: You are missing `die` after `header` call.

Comment: @Qeeet please don't call me sir. I'm also a beginner  :-) All the best for your exams.

Answer (score 1):

This code will never be executed:

```
if(isset($_POST["Submit"])){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['counter']=5;
    $_SESSION["lolvalue"]=isset($_POST["imie"]);
}
```

That's because your HTML form is sending `POST` request to `qwew.php` file not to `qwer.php`.

Comment: then how to make session work using submit button? I didnt find an answer on the internet yet

Comment: @Qeeet `I didnt find an answer on the internet yet` so you didn't even try to look for it. This code should be in file which will receive your `POST` request (`qwew.php` in that case).

Answer (score 0):

qwew.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["Submit"])){
    $_SESSION['counter']=5;
    $_SESSION["lolvalue"]=isset($_POST["imie"]);

    echo "here it is: ".$_SESSION["lolvalue"]." and ".$_SESSION["counter"];
}
?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="myform" method="post" action="qwew.php" onsubmit="return validateform();">
        <input type="text" name="imie"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit">
    </form>
    <a href='qwew.php'>Link to protected file</a>
    </body>
    </html>

<script type="text/javascript">function validateform(){
checkit=/^[A-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{7,16}$/;
if(!(myform.imie.value.match(checkit))){alert("blabla...bla");
return false;}
}
</script>
```

Comment: When it is done. I'm getting an error on qwew.php: Notice: Undefined index: lolvalue in C:\xampp\htdocs\qwew.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: counter in C:\xampp\htdocs\qwew.php on line 17
here it is: and

Comment: There is no `$_POST` in `form.php` file so your answer is wrong.

Comment: I have created all what you have done. And it still does not work. On qwew.php page it shows: here it is: and 5. There is no lolvalue variable

Comment: There is no error message. It shows "here it is: and 5" But after collon there should be string value I have put in textbox on previous page